# c# When imageList bind into ListView, imageList 1st image not displaying

Tags: c#, listview, c#-4.0, imagelist

I,am having a `Listview` controller bind with `imageList` both `Listview` items and `Imagelist` images add through a while loop. with `dataReader().` the problem is after adding both items, Listview item shows correct but 1st image not displaying means images starting from `2nd` listview item.  I checked every thing with debugging mode. then I confused on `imagelist`, because 1st time when it runs it shows `COUNT` as `1` then next loop again it's `COUNT` became `0` and the next time it `1,2,3,4,5,6`.... etc.

```
private void populate(MySqlDataReader data)
        {
            //ImageList
            ImageList imgList = new ImageList();

            //set listview category items as Large icons
            listView_Category.View = View.LargeIcon;
            imgList.Images.Clear();

            //ADD image list into Listview
            listView_Category.LargeImageList = imgList;

            Application.DoEvents();

            int i = 0;
            while (data.Read())
            {
                try
                {
                    imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/" + data.GetString(2)));
                }
                catch (Exception w)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(w.Message);
                }

                imgList.ImageSize = new Size(100, 100);
                imgList.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;

                listView_Category.Items.Add(data.GetString(1), i);
                i++;

            }
        }
```

I try to add images manually also... when it is not working. only it's adding images through a loop. is it a Language bug.?

```
//imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-1.jpg"));
            //imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-2.jpg"));
            //imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-3.jpg"));
            //imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-4.jpg"));
            //imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-5.jpg"));
            //imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-6.jpg"));
            //imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-7.jpg"));
            //imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-8.jpg"));
            //imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-9.jpg"));
            //imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-10.jpg"));
            //imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-11.jpg"));
            //imgList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(@"./" + populateFolder + "/image-12.jpg"));
```

[image]

[image]

Database

[image]

Comment: and you are sure that image1 and tweleve are in folder with same name and and filetype

Comment: yes they all are correct

Comment: is this windows form application or wpf ?

Comment: windows Form application.

Comment: ok let me try ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134167/discussion-between-yashveer-singh-and-user3722956).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this this  this code will rad all files from a folder and add show it in the listview . The you just need to change the logic for reading it form DB .

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var folderPath = @"c:\images\";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);

        var imageList = new ImageList();
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            try
            {
               imageList.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
            }
            catch{
                Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
            }
        }
        this.listView1.View = View.LargeIcon;
        imageList.ImageSize = new Size(128, 128);
        this.listView1.LargeImageList = imageList;

        for (int j = 0; j < imageList.Images.Count; j++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.ImageIndex = j;
            this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Display nothing !... but imglist count = 12.

Comment: @user3722956 did you changes listview1 to listView_Category . I have used my name please chaeck if names are correct

Comment: very strange . I tested on my local application with 4 images and it works like charm.  can you update the code you used after changing it

Comment: @user3722956 if you can share you code on google drive I can check if

Comment: sure.. I ll..send it

Comment: hi I checked the code . And I dont have my sql on my pc cannot check . But the code which I gave in answer should work . I think som eproblem in the result of the data returned from ur db may be image names or path . try to print them . But first try my code . Copy some image sin a folder change the path in my code . Ans paste my code delete yours so will see all the images

Comment: your code is working perfect. but the thing is It is necessary to get the data from database for dynamic view. anyway thankx for help.

Comment: @user3722956 : What I can do is to show how you can do it with EntityFramework and sql server.